# How to get screen size of device?

Tags: android

I would like to get the height of a android screen and if the screen inst a certain height, how would i go about doing this?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

If you want the display dimensions in pixels you can use this code:

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay(); 
int width = display.getWidth();
int height = display.getHeight();
```

Then you can add condition that compares the height to satisfy your needs.

In inches:

```
DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);
double x = Math.pow(dm.widthPixels/dm.xdpi,2);
double y = Math.pow(dm.heightPixels/dm.ydpi,2);
double screenInches = Math.sqrt(x+y);
Log.d("debug","Screen inches : " + screenInches);
```

Comment: So what if i wanted to go by the inch?

Comment: This is wrong !!! , this is not calculation of px it is calculation of dip. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6840904/how-to-get-the-screen-size-of-the-device/6841335#6841335

Comment: Take devices see their specifications and you will see that with this code you get wrong results !

Comment: Funny enough: SDK says that these methods are deprecated and should be replaced by getSize(Point), but the latter causes NoSuchMethodException at least on my device. I'm wondering what's the purpose of such deprecation...

Comment: @SargeBorsch What version of Android is your device running when you get this error? getSize(Point) is only in Android 3 and up. For anything less than 3, you'll need to use the old method.

Comment: @RevTyler 2.3.4. But why then they marked method as deprecated, if it is required to support Android 2.3.4 and, possibly, some other popular devices, which cannot be easily upgraded?

Comment: @SargeBorsch Deprecated doesn't mean you should never use it. Deprecated means that you should only use it if necessary. It has been replaced, but they keep the code there for older devices that can't be upgraded. You would do an `if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 13)` to determine whether you should use the new code, or deprecated code.

Comment: @Lukap thank you for your link, for that's the correct answer. Above code drove me crazy for past few days.

Answer (score 22):

From within activity:

```
int width = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth();
int height = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getHeight();
```

---

Or if you only have `Context` object:

```
WindowManager windowManager = (WindowManager)mContext.getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
int width = windowManager.getDefaultDisplay().getWidth();
int height = windowManager.getDefaultDisplay().getHeight()
```

---

**UPDATED**. How to detect your application runs on large screen:

```
//Android Level 9 and up:
Configuration config = getResources().getConfiguration();
if((config.screenLayout & Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK) ==  
    Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_XLARGE) 
{
    //xlarge screen
}
```

Comment: Ok thanks! so how would i compare that to say? 10.2 inch screen? like what metric does it go by?

Comment: Cool! Thanks man thats actually better!

Comment: Thanks. But I guess there is a small bug for the 'Context' object one. The constant should be 'Context.WINDOW_SERVICE' instead of plain 'WINDOW_SERVICE'.

Comment: getHeight() and getWidth() for getDefaultDisplay() are deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

In your onCreate or any other Activity method simply do:

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
int width = display.getWidth(); 
int height = display.getHeight();
```